# No se actualiza la imagen asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

El segundo action con POST  no funciona y no encuentro el error y cuando cargo la pagina me dice este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero es que al seleccionar la imagen me recargue la nueva imagen pero sin necesidad del boton submit, ahorita lo estaba usando con el boton:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["user"].ToString();
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var user =  db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
            //var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

        return View(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase Imagen1)
    {
        var id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["user"].ToString();
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var user = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
        //var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (Imagen1 != null && Imagen1.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            user.Imagen = new byte[Imagen1.ContentLength];
            Imagen1.InputStream.Read(user.Imagen, 0, Imagen1.ContentLength);
        }
        using (ModeloUnedMS objDataContext = new ModeloUnedMS())
        {
             AspNetUsers objEmp = user;
            objEmp.Imagen = user.Imagen;
            objDataContext.SaveChanges();
        };

        return View(user);
    }
```

Esta es la pantalla del index lo que no me sirve es la parte de subir la foto.
Al seleccionar la imagen que voy a subir no me actualiza la foto en la base de datos porque me lanza ese error al darle click al boton de submit y nose cual es la parte del codigo donde esta el error porque cuando pruebo el codigo y veo lo que obtienen de información, todos obtienen datos no vacios, entonces no se cual sera la parte del codigo donde esta el error, seria de mucha gratitud si alguien me ayudara con el codigo o con un ejemplo de como actualizo la imagen sin el boton submit y que se actualize la imagen.

```
@model Atencion_de_incidentes.Models.AspNetUsers
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

<!----------Inicio del dashboard.html---------->
<!-- page content -->
<div class="">
    <div class="page-title">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            <!--Fin de de generar un nueva categoria -->
            <div class="x_panel">
                <!--Inicio de las migas de pan-->
                <div class="form-group row x_title">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="control-label"><h3>Mi Perfil</h3></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Datos personales de mi perfil</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Inicio de la tabla-->
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="image view view-first">
                        <img class="thumb-image" style="width: 100%; display: block;" src="@Url.Action("convertirimagen","Home", new { id = Model.Id })" alt="Foto" />
                    </div>

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <p>Cambiar Imagen de perfil: </p><input type="file" id="Imagen1" name="Imagen1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Registrarse" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }

                    <div id="respuesta"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="x_panel">
                        <div class="x_title">
                            <h2>Informacion personal</h2>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x_content">
                            <br />
                            <form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="action/upd_profile.php" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">
                                        Nombre Completo
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NombreCompleto)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">
                                        Nombre Departamento
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Departamento)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">
                                        Número Telefónico
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">
                                        Correo electrónico
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Fin de la tabla-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /page content -->
```

Comment: Muestra la estructura de archivos que tienes, me late que la vista es inexistente o está mal configurada. Por otro lado, te hace falta javascript para que en cada cambio de imagen se lance una petición al servidor.